# Multiply several columns by Paramater

Tags: microsoft-excel, power, query

I have a set of budgeted columns - Jan, Feb, Mar, etc will sales values in a Foreign currency. I want to multiply all monthly columns by a FX rate enter via a Parameter. It this possible?

I know I could add a new column for the FX rate and then add additional columns to multiply each month by the FX value, but was hoping for a short cut.

Regards,
Jon

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is it really that time consuming?

Answer (score 0):

If ***FX*** is the same for all columns and all cells within the columns, then you can rely of the *distributive property* to keep the equation simple.  Say the raw values are in **A1** through **A10**, **C1** through **C10** and **G1** through **G10**. Put the conversion factor in cell **Z100** *(for example)* and then use:

```
=Z100*(SUM(A1:A10)+SUM(C1:C10)+SUM(G1:G10))
```

You don't have to multiply each cell by the factor.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to permanently convert the values to the new ones, or to keep them as they are but also show them in another currency?

If you want to permanently convert them, type your exchange rate in a cell. Copy. Select all the values and use Paste Special > Multiply